# wrong place for wavy-underline errors and warnings in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the python files of VS Code, the error and warnings wavy-underline are shown but under wrong place. 
For example, instead of underlining the exact error, it underlines a comment and shows the message of that error when the mouse pointer hovers over the comment. However, the intellisense is fine as the correct hint would appear correctly.

**What I have tried** : I tried to search through the setting section, but I haven't found the related setting

In where can I fix this wrong placement of error and warnings underline ?

ps 1 : I also notice most of the warning message are related to torch,for example
an error is which I suspect might be related :

```
torch has no sum member
```

then I found this https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1942, and add torch correspondingly and it seems the error has gone.

Comment: some errors cannot be identified, except by unexpected text after the error location ... that unexpected text should be underlined, but the underline does not indicate the actual location of the error

Comment: So it’s a normal case?